# SQL Server CASE statement with subquery in then

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the `case` statement below but despite it having the values that should trigger the case's, I am still getting nulls. Any obvious errors?

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (CASE
        WHEN topicname = 'TPOSTAL_CODE' 
           THEN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ALS_C)) AS LocationCode
                 FROM ODS.TBUS_LOC
                 WHERE cci.columna = ods.TBUS_LOC.BUS_LOC_I)
        WHEN topicname = 'TBUSINESS_SITE' 
           THEN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(B.ALS_C)) AS LocationCode
                 FROM ODS.TBUSINESS_SITE A
                 INNER JOIN ODS.TBUS_LOC B ON A.BUS_LOC_ID = B.BUS_LOC_I
                 WHERE cci.columna = A.BUS_LOC_ID)
     END) AS Code
FROM 
    [XREF].[tablea] CCI
```

`CCIEntityName` with a distinct

[image]

Comment: Try testing for the presence of nulls: add WHERE ALS_C IS NULL. Or add ISNULL (ALS_C, 'THIS IS NULL'), or COALESCE

Comment: Could you please attach sample data and the schema of the underlying tables?

Comment: Expected results will help as well.

Comment: you need to test your sub queries individually.  also add an ELSE 'not there' END to the CASE statement to see if it is selecting any of the conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that topicname contains spaces either at the beginning or the end.  These may not be readily visible to the eye.  You might try

> CASE   WHEN ltrim(rtrim(topicname)) = 'TPOSTAL_CODE'

and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Must be spaces at the beginning, trailing spaces are ignored in comparisons.